# Java Exception - Socket is closed, reliable udp help?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, udp, inputstream

I'm currently using a Java implementation of the Reliable UDP protocol, found [here][1]. The project has absolutely no tutorials so I have found it really hard to identify problems.

I have set up a client and server. The server runs on localhost:1234 and the client runs on localhost:1235. The server is first established, and loops listening for connections.

I then have set it to send a packet to the server. When a packet is sent, the server calls handlePacket() -

```
DataInputStream i = new DataInputStream(client.getSocket().getInputStream());
            short packetID = i.readShort();
            i = null;
            switch(packetID){
                case 3:
                    Packeta packeta = new Packeta(client);
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm currently using a debugging with a small dummy class called Packeta. When the constructor is called, it reads from a stream and the logs to the console. However, always when constructing, it hangs for 10 seconds, before producing the error -

> java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed ....
>   at
>   lessur.engine.net.packets.Packeta.(Packeta.java:15)

The constructor for Packeta -

```
public Packeta(LessurConnectedNode c) {
        super((short)3, c);
        try {
            /*LINE 15*/ Logger.getLogger("adsfas").info("X was "+c.getSocket().getInputStream().read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It has something todo with the input streams. I don't know what is wrong, but from reading other threads, it might be todo with having multiple inputstreams. I'm lost on this, please help.

Comment: Aren't the client and server supposed to connect to the same socket? For example server connected to localhost:1234 and client to localhost:1234?

Comment: I'm don't understand all details of question, but recently i have the same exception on other situation. In my case socket was closed by connection timeout and I solve the problem by increasing server's connection timeout param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was passing the server to the socket listener, before the socket was fully initialized. FIXED!